# How to get attribute from AttributeContainer in UIKit and assign it to some variable

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton, attributedstring

I create next subclass:

```
import UIKit

class Button: UIButton {

    override func updateConfiguration() {
        var config = configuration ?? UIButton.Configuration.plain()

        let color = config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor

        switch state {
        case .normal:
            config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor = color.withAlphaComponent(1)

        case .highlighted:
            config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        default:
            break
        }

        configuration = config
    }
}
```

I this class I want to get foregroundColor from attributedTittle(AttributedString class) to assign it later with alphaComponent to different button states, BUT I can't get any attribute  from attributedString(or AttributedContainer) in updateConfiguration method.
In my example property "color" is always nil (actually all other attribute are nil if I try get them) and the return type of "color" is:

```
AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.ForegroundColorAttribute.Value?
```

And I get this error when try to assign color back to attributedString:

```
 Value of type 'AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.ForegroundColorAttribute.Value?' (aka 'Optional<Color>') has no member 'withAlphaComponent'
```

So why I can't get any attributes from AttributedString here?

Comment: What do you mean by you "can't" get any attribute? What did the code do and what did you expect? Can you show a [mcve]? Also, I don't think you should mix `setAttributedTitle` with the configuration APIs.

Comment: @Sweeper 
I change my code, so you can understand what i expect. About mixing it, I think it doest not matter, because config.attributedString still have all attribute which I assigned with  `setAttributedTitle `.
I also try to assign my custom `AttributedString` to `configuration.attributedString` and still have same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the compiler is prioritising the `foregroundColor` in the `SwiftUIAttributes` attribute scope. You can force it to choose the UIKit one by specifying the type of `color`.

```
let color: UIColor? = config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor
```

Alternatively, access the `uiKit` attribute scope directly:

```
let color = config.attributedTitle?.uiKit.foregroundColor
```

Note that this should be an optional type, so you should unwrap it when you use `withAlphaComponent`:

```
config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor = color?.withAlphaComponent(1)
                                               ^
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works. 
Btw, I tried `let color = config.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor as? UIColor`, but it doesn't work, so I was confused.